# Filter Django model based on other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-filter

I have two models Wellinfo and LOGRD_RPT

```
class Wellinfo (models.Model):
    WellID    = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    Perimeter = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class LOGRD_RPT(models.Model):
    WellID    = models.CharField(max_length=15, validators= [validate_textComptn])
```

I need to get a list of WellID (ListaWells) from the first model Wellinfo based on two conditions:

1- Perimeter.

2- if the WellID exists in the second model LOGRD_RPT

So the First step is to get all wells that belong to a Field='FD1' in the Wellinfo model

```
ListaWells=   Wellinfo.objects.filter(Perimeter=Field)
```

then I need to exclude the wells that don't exist in the 2nd model LOGRD_RPT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) subquery:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

ListaWells = Wellinfo.objects.annotate(
    log_exists=Exists(LOGRD_RPT.objects.filter(WellID=OuterRef("WellID")))
).filter(Perimetre=Field, log_exists=True)
```

Or shorter:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

ListaWells = Wellinfo.objects.filter(
    Exists(LOGRD_RPT.objects.filter(WellID=OuterRef("WellID"))),
    Perimetre=Field,          
)
```

Comment: Many thanks but the first it give me this error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Perimeter' into field. Choices are: Perimetre, WellID,

and the Shorter one this error!

 Exists(LOGRD_RPT.objects.filter(WellID=OuterRef("WellID"))),
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

How ever I solved it bu hard way :)

Comment: @tibas looks like it should be `Perimetre`, check updated answer.

Comment: Now they work well. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works with this

```
ListaWells = Wellinfo.objects.filter(Perimeter=Field)
ListaWell = Wellinfo.objects.filter(Perimeter=Field).values_list('WellID', flat=True).distinct()
LogaWells = LOGRD_RPT.objects.values_list('WellID', flat=True).distinct()
for well in ListaWell:
    if well not in LogaWells:
        ListaWells = ListaWells.exclude(WellID__exact= well)
```

and I think the way posted by neverwalkaloner is better if it works.
any other suggestions?